# Installing Zend_Barcode

Tags: magento2, composer, zend-framework, barcode, zend

I'm not having any luck getting Zend_Barcode to work in Magento 2.

Zend_PDF is working, and I notice that it has a class in:

```
/vendor/zendframework1/library/Zend/
```

but Zend_Barcode does not.

I've tried:

```
composer require zendframework/zend-barcode
```

But that isn't a version that's compatible with Magento's Zend_Pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out it was removed in version 2.3. Which is a shame.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/#application-framework-libraries

Comment: was you able to get it working? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @jefferson Unfortunately not, I ended up adapting a barcode generator I found on GitHub into a Magento 2 class.